# Android - for loop: for (boolean bool = true; ; bool = false)

Tags: android

The following snippet is part of a Human Step Detection Android App
downloaded from the Play Store. Since it works fine, so I assume the
codes all make sense.

```
private boolean isMotion(float[] paramArrayOfFloat)
{
    if ((Math.abs(this.mOldAcc[0] - paramArrayOfFloat[0]) > 1.0F) || (Math.abs(this.mOldAcc[1] - paramArrayOfFloat[1]) > 1.0F) ||
        (Math.abs(this.mOldAcc[2] - paramArrayOfFloat[2]) > 1.0F));
        for (boolean bool = true; ; bool = false)
        {
            this.mOldAcc[0] = paramArrayOfFloat[0];
            this.mOldAcc[1] = paramArrayOfFloat[1];
            this.mOldAcc[2] = paramArrayOfFloat[2];
            return bool;
        }
}
```

Regarding the following codes, I have two questions:

1) The looping condition:

`for (boolean bool = true; ; bool = false){}`

This condition means that every time my loop starts, bool is set to
 true. Then when the loop is finished, bool is set to false. What is
 the purpose of doing so? In addition, what is the point of doing so
 here?

2) the if condition:

`if ((Math.abs(this.mOldAcc[0] - paramArrayOfFloat[0]) > 1.0F) || 
     (Math.abs(this.mOldAcc[1] - paramArrayOfFloat[1]) > 1.0F) || (Math.abs(this.mOldAcc[2] 
     -paramArrayOfFloat[2]) > 1.0F));`

The if condition is directly finished by adding a ; right after the
 condition. Really have no idea why this has been done.

Someone please help me. Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for`-loop one *could* be useful in the case where you want to do something different the first time through the loop:

```
for (boolean firstTime = true; ; firstTime = false) {
    if (firstTime)
        doStuff();
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

It's not how I'd choose to do it but I guess it's plausible. In any case, the body of the loop makes the setting of the boolean value irrelevant since it returns no matter what.

How you describe it is not totally correct by the way. The first time the loop starts, it's set to true, but it's when an *iteration* of the loop restarts that it gets set to false.

When the *loop* ends (presumably with a `break` since otherwise the loop *doesn't* end), the boolean is not set to anything - it's scope is limited to the loop itself.

The `if`-statement one (with no body) could only be useful if there was a side-effect in the conditions themselves (such as a function call making changes somewhere). This is not the case with standard `Math` function so that one seems *truly* useless.

Bottom line, that code appears to have been written by a severely broken code generator or a coder that is either psychopathic or has very little ability (or maybe, just maybe, it's not yet finished).

Comment: Yeah. Thanks! So for the given snippet, the for loop never stops, does it?

Comment: @perfectionming, technically, yes, the `for` loop doesn't stop. However, since you return from within it, you're "jumping out" of it.

Comment: But since the app works perfectly fine on my phone, I really cannot assure that this part is POINTLESS.

Comment: @perfectionming, all my code still works when I add: `if (false) {int i = 1;};` but that's still pointless.

Comment: true... but the whole function is called isMotion, so it seems that it is DESIGNED to detect the motion, which it fails to do. Thanks!

Comment: @perfectionming: and yes, that loop is no different to just the three assignments followed by `return true;`.

Answer (score 0):

(1) is pointless unless `bool` is used within the loop, which it isn't, and it isn't even a loop because it returns, so it is just pointless.

(2) is just pointless.

Comment: Yeah. I thought the same as you said. But since the app works perfectly fine on my phone, I really cannot assure that this part is POINTLESS.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work. I said it was pointless. You could remove the for-loop statement and return true and it would still work. QED. Similarly you could write 'return true|true|true' etc and it would still work. And be pointless.